# Spacing between words in footnote is wrong (too big)

Tags: footnotes

I have a footnote but the spacing is not correct. How do I fix this?

```
\footnote{The source code is available at \url{https://github.com/HaziqRazali/Pedestrian-Intention-Prediction}.}.
```

[image]

Comment: The problem here is the url.  Although it contains hyphens, breaking at one of them might be confusing, since it wouldn't be clear whether it was added at the break, or part of the url itself.  (And the spacing might still not be ideal.)  This is probably a case where an explicit break -- using `\\ ` -- would be the best choice.  `\raggedright` might also be an option.  Both the `url` and `hyperref` packages offer provisions to allow breaks, but this particular url is problematic in that regard.

Comment: Try loading the `xurl` package, then `\url` will break at any point not just allowable breakpoints for URLS

Comment: @barbarabeeton thank you the \raggedright option works perfect :)

Answer (score 3):

The usual advice for breaking urls is to take advantage of the breaking facilities in a package; `url`, `xurl` (suggested by @daleif), and `hyperref` all provide useful options.

However, this particular url already contains hyphens, and breaking at a hyphen might create confusion since it may not be entirely clear that the hyphen is part of the url itself.  (Also, given the size of the "logical" segment before the probable break vs. the space available in the stretched line, the spacing may still be suboptimal.)  A two-line footnote doesn't have much freedom for reflowing the lines.

I conclude, therefore, that simply breaking this into two lines, leaving the first line short, is the best approach.  Two possibilities are the following:

- apply `\raggedright`, and let the line-breaking do what it will;
- break the line explicitly with `\\` at the point you think is best.  Use of the double backslash is recommended only rarely except in the situations it was designed for (between rows in tables, or indicating a line break in multi-line display mathematics), but this is a legitimate exception.

The `\raggedright` approach has been adopted here, as noted in a comment.